# Dereferencing array pointer in a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How do you deference a pointer to an array to get the value stored in it? For example:

```
void testFunction(int **test){
  printf("%d", *test[1]);
}

int main()
{   int test[10];
    test[1] = 5;
    testFunction(&test);
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error. Anyone could explain?

Comment: "I get an error" is not very helpful.  Is it a compiler error or a runtime error.  What is the error message or symptom?  Why are you not compiling with more warnings enabled? (Your compiler should be complaining about a type mismatch between `int (*)[10]` and `int **`.)  Why are you not fixing the warnings before running the program?  Remember, your C compiler knows more about C than you do.

Comment: Is the signature of the function you're trying to call fixed?  Do you have to call `void testFunction(int **test){...}` or could you change that to `void testFunction(int (*i)[10]){...}`?

Comment: Ok, it works, but I am still confused. Why int **  isn't same as int (*)[]? Since test is pointer to first element, then pointer to it should be just int **, no?

Comment: @user1242967 `int **` is the address of a pointer to an int.  In other words the address of a memory location that hold the address to an int. A two-step reference so to speak. A pointer to an array however, is just the address of the array, which boils down to be a pointer to the first element of the array; and thus this is similar to a single `int *`. The confusing thing is that the plain array identifier `test` and `&test` can both be used; they are equivalent. So your code above is correct with just `int *test`.  HTH

Comment: Next time please use different names for parameter and variable. Using the same `test` twice makes things harder to write about.

Answer (score 3):

> How do you deference a pointer to an array to get the value stored in it?

You use the `*` operator, as for every pointer. (Oh, and pay attention to operator precedence!)

```
void foo(int (*arr)[5])
{
    printf("%d\n", (*arr)[0]);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    foo(&arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: lol... I didn't downvote, but I love the assertion that the downvote was wrong.

Comment: @GradyPlayer Honestly, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, it works, but could you explain why mine code didn't work? Isn't type int (*)[] same as int **?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it, but I don't really see the utility to this, it is just so static.

Comment: @user1242967 no, arrays are not pointers. [Read this.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

Comment: arrays are usually stack allocated, and passing out pointers to different scopes is dangerous in general... then typing statically the size of the array... I know you have answered the question, but it is kind of smelly.

Comment: @GradyPlayer What? What are you even talking about? Have you never passed pointers to local variables to a function? And what's wrong with "typing statically the size of the array"? If you want to make sure there is the correct number of initializer elements specified (and ensure that the compiler warns), then it's *just appropriate.*

Comment: So, if I changed the arr to his
int *ptrarr = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
the function wouldn't work? In this case I should change the type of arr parameter in function to int **arr?

Comment: @user1242967 Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code would have generated a diagnostic about an incompatible type being passed to the function. For example, GCC complains:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:9: warning: passing argument 1 of 'testFunction' from incompatible pointer type
```

You should pay attention to all diagnostics issued by your compiler, and make sure you understand them, and take the appropriate measures to address them. For this particular one, if you intend to pass in a pointer to an array, you need to write your function to accept such a thing. Then, when you dereference the pointer, you have an array. So, you access it like one.

```
void testFunction(int (*test)[10]){
  printf("%d", (*test)[1]);
}
```

The `[]` has higher precedence that `*`, so the parentheses are required both for the function parameter argument, and for accessing the value in the `printf()`. When the pointer to `int[10]` is derferenced, the resulting value is the address of the first element of the array `test` defined in `main`. The `[]` operation then access the 2nd element of the array, and you get the value you expected.

---

You may be more convinced that your use of `int **test` is wrong for a pointer to an array if you note that the assertion below will always be true:

```
int test[10];
assert(&test == (void *)test);
```

As the compiler warning indicates, a pointer to a pointer to `int` is not the same as a pointer to an `int[10]`. The type being pointed to determines the type that results from a dereference.

So:

```
int test[10] = { [1] = 5 };
testFunction(&test);
```

This passes the address of `test` to `testFunction`. The address of a variable corresponds to its location in memory. This is not so different for an array, but the location in memory for an array variable is the address of its first element. So, the address returned by `&test` above is the same address returned by `test` alone.

This gives a disastrous consequence when you treat this pointer value as a pointer to a pointer to `int` in your `testFunction`. First, note that you ignore proper operator precedence, so the first dereference is:

```
test[1]
```

Since you declare the `test` parameter to be a pointer to a pointer to `int`, this increments the address in `test` by `sizeof(int *)` and treats the result as an `int *`. Then, you dereference again:

```
*test[1]
```

This now takes the value of `test[1]` and dereferences it again in an attempt to get an `int`. However, the address returned by `test[1]` has no relationship with the array `test` defined in `main`, and you are accessing a totally nonsensical memory location.

Even if you paid attention to the precedence with your pointer to pointer to `int` parameter type, a similar problem would have resulted.

```
(*test)[1]
```

Now, the pointer to `int[10]` is treated as a pointer to pointer to `int` is derferenced first. This results in the first `sizeof(int **)` bytes of the `test` array in `main` to be treated as a pointer to `int`. This is already a nonsensical value at this point, but the array dereference now increments this value by `sizeof(int)` bytes and dereferences that value in an attempt to obtain an `int`.

Comment: Constructive criticism appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The other user gave an example of how it is usually done already, but if you insist on passing an int ** then because of operator precedence the syntax would be like:

```
void testFunction(int **test){
  printf("%d", (*test)[1]);
}

int main()
{   int test[10];
    test[1] = 5;

    int *testptr= &test[0];  // or int *testptr= test;
    testFunction(&testptr);  // this passes an int **
    return 0;
}
```

But in c the name of an array is a pointer to the array elements, so int *ptrtest and ptrtest[1] is more commonly used.

Comment: This is wrong, arrays are not pointers, pointers to arrays are not double pointers.

Comment: The name of an array is a pointer to the first element.  Although you are right, &array is not a double pointer.

Comment: no, the name of the array is the name of the array. It can *decay into* a pointer to the first element under certain circumstances. If it was a pointer, then there's a good chance `sizeof(int [1])` would be the same as `sizeof(int [1000])`, although it certainly isn't.